# Python, problem with json.loads when trying to work with/upload files via O365/Sharepoint API

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, sharepoint

I'm using the below code to connect to sharepoint for the purpose of uploading files to a site. all of the auth stuff is fine, for some reason I'm getting a json decode error. Anything obvious here? Assume flow starts with function "getSharepointContext()". I've gone through numerous other tutorials and questions regarding this, and everything seems ok and consistent.

The purpose is to iterate through each file in a local folder and upload to a sharepoint site/folder.

Obviously something wrong with the request and json.loads but if anybody who has more experience working with files like this sees something, I would be appreciative!

```
import os
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from logger import Logger

def getSharepointContext():
    sharepointUrl = 'https://url.sharepoint.com/site/folder/'
    clientCredentials = ClientCredential('a79f867e-3138-4qwdqwdqwdqwdqwdffe3', '_vp8Q~05OqwdqwdqwdqwdyCb_gQppjen8czP')
    ctx = ClientContext(sharepointUrl).with_credentials(clientCredentials)
    targetFolder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(sharepointUrl)
    uploadFiles(targetFolder)

def uploadFiles(targetFolder):
    wd = os.getcwd()
    td = wd+'/toUpload'
    for fn in os.listdir(td):
        f = os.path.join(td, fn)
        if os.path.isfile(f):
            with open(f, 'rb') as k:
                Logger.log('Uploading: ' + f, 1, True)
                file_content = k.read()
                print(file_content)
                targetFolder.upload_file(f, file_content).execute_query()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    getSharepointContext()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mnowicky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\projects\odUploader_py\uploadFiles.py", line 46, in <module>
    getSharepointContext()
  File "D:\projects\odUploader_py\uploadFiles.py", line 17, in getSharepointContext
    uploadFiles(targetFolder)
  File "D:\projects\odUploader_py\uploadFiles.py", line 31, in uploadFiles
    targetFolder.upload_file(f, file_content).execute_query()
  File " \client_object.py", line 44, in execute_query
    self.context.execute_query()
  File " \client_runtime_context.py", line 161, in execute_query
    self.pending_request().execute_query(qry)
  File " \client_request.py", line 57, in execute_query
    response = self.execute_request_direct(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File " \client_request.py", line 69, in execute_request_direct
    self.beforeExecute.notify(request)
  File " \types\event_handler.py", line 21, in notify
    listener(*args, **kwargs)
  File  , line 221, in _build_modification_query
    self._ensure_form_digest(request)
  File  , line 157, in _ensure_form_digest
    self._ctx_web_info = self._get_context_web_information()
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File  , line 170, in _get_context_web_information
    client.map_json(response.json(), return_value, json_format)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a more convenient way to do this is to use the Microsoft Graph API, which provides a dedicated upload API endpoint, you can reference these documentations:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0

small size upload:

`PUT /drives/{drive-id}/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content`

Resumable upload:

`POST /drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/createUploadSession`

`PUT https://sn3302.up.1drv.com/up/fe6987415ace7X4e1eF866337`

`Content-Length: 26`

`Content-Range: bytes 0-25/128`